# Rewriting elements in html by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

i have a a code like that:

```
<p id = "outputLaps"></p>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").innerHTML = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds
```

and i don't want to rewrite it, but to display it under the previous "lap". 
Thanks for answers :).

Comment: Maybe you should be using `<ol>` or `<ul>` instead of `<p>`?

Comment: Try `.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', yourString)` instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) when you want to insert HTML.

```js
var str = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;
document.getElementById("outputLaps").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str);
```

However, if you only want to insert text, you can append a text node:

```js
var str = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;
document.getElementById("outputLaps").appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(str)
);
```

In case you want the text to go to the next line, you can either

- Insert a newline character `\n` and style the paragraph with [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) set to `pre`, `pre-wrap` or `pre-line`.
- Insert a `<br />` HTML element.
- Use different paragraphs. Seems the most semantic.

Comment: Ok, that works great, but does it works on every browsers? I'm asking just because that link comes from Mozilla.

Comment: @cerbin See [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#Browser_Compatibility). In fact, it seems Firefox was the last to implement it. Previously it was a non-standard IE thing.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @cerbin MDN is not Mozilla-specific. It's a Wiki that's used to document HTML, JS, CSS, etc. across all browsers. It's just hosted by Mozilla.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use `<ol>` or `<ul id="outputLaps">` instead, and add `<li>s` to it.

```
var li = document.createElement( 'li' )
li.textContent = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds

document.getElementById( 'outputLaps' ).appendChild( li )
```

In this case, because `.appendChild()` returns the element being added, we can avoid the variable.

```
document.getElementById( 'outputLaps' )
        .appendChild( document.createElement( 'li' ) )
        .textContent = "Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds
```

---

Maybe you don't want the ugly bullets, so you can change them, or simply remove them with a CSS rule:

```
<style>
    ul { list-style-type: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+=` to concatenate to the existing value.

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").innerHTML += "<br>Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds
```

You can also use the [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method, which doesn't modify the existing DOM nodes in the paragraph.

```
document.getElementById("outputLaps").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br>Number of lap: " + numberOfLap + " time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds);
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Because `.innerHTML +=` is harmful. It will stupidly serialize and reparse previous contents. And all the internal data will be lost.

Comment: @Oriol No it's not harmful, but there are possible better ways of doing it.

Comment: Oh, that's working fine, didn't think about it, thanks. But appart from that, i heard something like you shouldn't use <br /> on website, is that true? Thanks :).

Comment: @Oriol It's harmful if the contents may have event handlers on it. But for simple formatted text it's fine.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: It's not? So destroying the old DOM and recreating it with the new elements added has no negative side-effects?

Comment: @squint What are you talking about? That's not at all what it's doing.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Actually, that's what it does. It reads the old HTML, concatenates the strings, then stores that as the new HTML. So it reparses everything from scratch.

Comment: @squint It's only destroying the DOM of the paragraph element, not the entire document, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: That's exactly what it's doing. https://jsfiddle.net/tap3yd3k/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Ugh... the DOM nodes. It's destructive and unnecessary.

Comment: @squint Since there are no dynamic properties in this list of output, that's not a concern. But I've added code to my answer showing how to do it non-destructively with `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, it's not an issue in this small example. I think we both know that new users would go ahead and use this in other situations though. (FWIW, I didn't vote, since it's not technically incorrect.)